How to add exception context in my Python code?
Say I want to reraise an exception with extra information for handling - what would be the best practice for that?
I came up with the following but it smells fishy to me:
def internal_function():
    raise ValueError("smelly socks!")
    
def context_function():
    try:
        internal_function()
    except Exception as e:
        e.args= e.args[:1] + ("<raise_context>",) + e.args[1:]  # raise context varies on conditions ofc
        raise e

def handler_function():
    try:
        context_function()
    except Exception as e:
        msg, context, *other = e.args 
        if context == "some_context":
            pass # handle one way
        elif context == "some other context":
            pass # handle another way`

wants to amend the message string rather than adding separate metadata.

re-raise as a new exception like raise MyException(e.args[0], "my context", e.args[1:]) from e. Python exception class takes and stores arbitrary *args. You can give meaning to these args by subclassing the base Exception and storing them into specific instance attrs in MyException.__init__ method

Why did you tag this as asp.net?
